# Trying to make my first Java program work

Tags: java

Why do I keep getting the

> error: class, interface, or enum expected

for my syntax on line 3 `Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Because you are missing ***both*** *class* and *method* **declarations**.

Comment: Yeah, wow, I'm usually not critical about questions, but you are abusing this site with that one.

Comment: @BrianAmante I suggest you go through a basic tutorial...

Comment: Your line `Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` has to be (1) within a class, and (2) within a class method or static initializer block.

Comment: I highly suggest starting with a basic Java example program.  You can find one at http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11hello/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are here to help each other learn to program. Your first program is missing several pieces in order to work correctly. However, we do not like to repeat information that is already widely available. I strongly suggest that you find a good tutorial to learn these basics. Oracle has a very good one on the official Java website. Good luck!

Comment: Note that the error tells you the exact problem. Your computer expects one of the three words in the message. As I said earlier, the Oracle tutorial will teach you the correct way to write your program.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this snippet helps you. It contains almost what you want.
In Linux, save it as `Program.java` (must be named as the main class), try 'compiling' it with `javac Program.java`, and executing it with `java Program` NOTE:The executable class file wont be named `Program`, but `Program.class`

```
import java.util.*; //Import Scanner etc.

public class Program { //Main Class, needed
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Main Function(executed), must be in Main Class
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //Input
        System.out.println("Whats your name ?"); //Prints a new line
        String name = in.nextLine(); //Name
        System.out.println("Your name is "+name); //Prints a new line
    }
}
```